# Как вызвать камеру в Windows Phone 8/10?

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-10-mobile, windows-phone-8.1

Как можно вызвать камеру на C# для Windows Phone? Я находил только для Windows Phone 7 или 7.1, но это не подошло, т.к. мне надо для Windows Phone 10, ну или хотя бы для 8-8.1.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галочка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот, нашел решение **[здесь](https://blog.zwezdin.com/2013/windows-phone-camera-access/)**, кому интересно))))

Answer (score 2):

**Windows Phone 8.x**

Использовать [`CameraCaptureTask`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.tasks.cameracapturetask(v=vs.105).aspx):

```
var cameraCaptureTask = new CameraCaptureTask();
cameraCaptureTask.Completed += cameraCaptureTask_Completed;
cameraCaptureTask.Show();

...

private void cameraCaptureTask_Completed(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        // Отобразим фотографию в контроле myImage
        var bmp = new BitmapImage();
        bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);
        myImage.Source = bmp;
    }
}
```

Однако имейте в виду, что все фотографии, снятые таким образом, автоматически попадут в фотоальбом. И если у пользователя при этом включена автозагрузка фотографий, они попадут в интернет. Если это поведение является нежелательным (нужно делать временные или личные снимки), то необходимо воспользоваться классом `PhotoCamera` и [самостоятельно реализовать](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh202956(v=vs.105).aspx) съемку.

**Windows 10 Mobile**

Использовать [`CameraCaptureUI`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/audio-video-camera/capture-photos-and-video-with-cameracaptureui).